# Sqlserver group by pending days period

Tags: sql-server

I have table structure as below,

```
State   Application_count   Pending_Days
_________________________________________
TN            10               0
TN            20               1
TN            60               2
TN            10               3
MH            40               1
MH            50               3
MH            20               5
MH            30               8
```

I want to sum Application_count based on State and Pending_Days period.
I have to group Pending_days 0 to 1 Days, 1 to 3 days, morethan 3 days

**Expected Output:**

```
State   Application_count   
_________________________

  TN         30
  TN         70
  MH         40
  MH         50
  MH         50
```

Comment: If `0-1` is `30` then for `1-3` it will be `90`, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give an additional column, `group_num` using a `CASE` expression based on the condition of `Pending_Days` column.

Then find the sum group by `group_num` and `state` columns.

**Query**

```
select t.[state], sum(t.[Application_Count]) as [Application_Count] from(
    select [group_num] = (
        case when [Pending_Days] between 0 and 1 then 1 
        when [Pending_Days] between 2 and 3 then 2
        when [Pending_Days] > 3 then 3 else 4 end
    ), * 
    from [your_table_name]
)t
group by t.[group_num], t.[state];
```

[**Find demo here**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/542964/sqlserver-group-by-pending-days-period-demo)

**Note:**

For `Pending_Days` condition, `0 to 1 Days` I have taken 0 and 1
for `1 to 3 days` I have taken 2 and 3 , for `morethan 3 days` I have taken the value greater than 3.